# Deploying Lambda with Cloud9

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, cloud9, aws-sam-cli, aws-cloud9

Hello here is my project structure:

`-AppName
    -Common
        -common.js //Global module which i'm using in all functions
    -Func1
        -index.js
    -Func2
        -index.js
    -template.yaml`

And here is template.yaml content:

`AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.
Resources:
      Func1:
        Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
          Handler: Func1/index.handler
          Runtime: nodejs6.10
          MemorySize: 512
          Timeout: 10
      Func2:
        Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
          Handler: Func2/index.handler
          Runtime: nodejs6.10
          MemorySize: 512
          Timeout: 10`

When i deploy for example Func2, result package contain all folders inside application, instead only Func2. Is it possible to configure through yaml file, what files will included in result package?
For example if i deploy Func2 i want to see in package next:

`-Common
    -common.js
-Func2
    -index.js`

Comment: Anyone have ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CodeUri` key in SAM and point it to the folder where your code lies for that one function.

So for this function, you'd want to do:

```
  Func2:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      CodeUri: Func2
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 10
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I think in this case i will lost connection with Common folder which is also needed for each function